# Exception from writeln function if the input size is big

Tags: d

I am reading the amplitudes of a audio file in D. From string I am converting the into float[]
Than I am writing it like :

```
    auto amplitudeByTime = file2string("data8.txt");//file2string returns a float[] with size I determine. 
    writeln(amplitudeByTime);
```

Everything is ok if the size of float[] is 1660(or less) but when it to 1661(or more) writeln throws an exception like:

```
std.stdio.StdioException@std\stdio.d(2431): Bad file descriptor
----------------
0x0040EA7B
0x00411F62
0x0040FD80
0x0040FDBB
0x0040F9B9
0x0040B774
0x75EDD2E9 in BaseThreadInitThunk
0x77BF1603 in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
0x77BF15D6 in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
----------------
```

Do you have any idea about what might be problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in writeln. Could you please submit to http://d.puremagic.com/issues, possibly with a file that reproduces the problem? OS and version info would help too. Thanks!

Comment: Done . Can you please check Issue 11040 if anything missing from my side I will add if something needed.

Comment: BTW it very nice to get a real response from you after I read your doc all day. :: http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357&rll=1 , perfect document.